# What is the so called diagonal method?

Tags: analysis

It is usual when I read a paper to see the authors referring a diagonal method. For instance, if $(f_n)$ is a sequence of real-valued functions on $X$ and $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $X$ such that $\{ f_i(x_j) : i,j \in \mathbb N \}$ is bounded, they applied this so called diagonal method to obtain a subsequence $(x_{n_j})$ of $(x_n)$ and $\alpha_i \in \mathbb R$ such that $f_i(x_{n_j}) \to \alpha_i$ as $j \to \infty$.

My thought was: Since, for each $i$, the sequence $(f_i(x_n))_n$ is bounded in $\mathbb R$, we can find a convergent subsequence $(f_i(x_{n_{j, i}}))_j$ and we call the limit $\alpha_i$. We have

$$ x_{n_{1,1}}, \quad x_{n_{2,1}}, \quad x_{n_{3,1}} \quad \cdots \quad x_{n_{j,1}} \quad \cdots $$
$$ x_{n_{1,2}}, \quad x_{n_{2,2}}, \quad x_{n_{3,2}} \quad \cdots \quad x_{n_{j,2}} \quad \cdots $$
$$ x_{n_{1,3}}, \quad x_{n_{2,3}}, \quad x_{n_{3,3}} \quad \cdots \quad x_{n_{j,3}} \quad \cdots $$

If we put $x_{n_j} = x_{n_{j,j}}$, we have that $f_i(x_{n_j}) \to \alpha_i$ for all $i$? If so, this does not seem so obvious to me.

I was looking for some explanation of this method or some references.

Comment: It won't work if you choose the subsequences independently. You should rather choose them recursively, each being a subsequence of the previous one.

Comment: Can you give a reference to the paper you are reading, please. That will make it easier for us to provide an answer.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff%27s_theorem